# Why the weight function should be nonzero when the interval is $[0,\infty)$?

Tags: stieltjes-integral

In Riemann-Stieltjes integral,

$ \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) w(x)dx$

why the weight function should be nontrivial when the interval is $[0,\infty)$?

Comment: That is just a Riemann integral with integrand $f(x)w(x)$. A Riemann-Stieltjes integral has the form $$\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dw(x)$$ If $w$ is continuously differentiable, then the Riemann-Stieltjes integral can be converted to a Riemann integral by $$\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dw(x) = \int_0^\infty f(x)w'(x)\,dx$$ But otherwise they are distinct from each other. In the actual Riemann-Stieltjes integral, if $w$ is constant ($0$ or not), then $dw(x) \equiv 0$, and thus the whole integral is $0$, regardless of $f$.

Comment: Thank you so much.